# Tool to write an object instance to C# (for unit testing)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Say I have a method that takes a list of objects.  The method will normally take 20 objects easy.  Each object has 15 or so properties on them.

To unit test this, I need to type out all 20 objects so that I can pass them into my method.

This is frustrating when I can see perfectly good examples of what I need sitting there in my debugger watch window.

Is there a tool to take an object that I have and make it output to C#?

NOTE: I saw this question: [How can I serialize an object to C# object initializer code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5793867/16241) but the code it generates does not work...

I can't think I am the first to want this.  Is it harder than I think? or are there tools out there that do it already?

Comment: sounds like your method needs redesigned.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. but as a side note I would recommend thinking about extending that list. Would you mind posting that method?

Comment: Factory pattern + Random.Next are your friends here.

Comment: The method is a hypothetical one.  I am just proposing it to illustrate what I am looking for.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - The idea is that these objects are loaded from the database.  So to unit test using the objects I need to create them manually.  They cannot be random.  The data in them is what will determine if my tests pass or fail.

Comment: Try NBuilder to build your test objects http://nbuilder.org/

Answer (score 3):

I created a visual studio plugin called [Object Exporter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6a21c68-f815-4895-999f-cd0885d8774f) which does exactly this. You can export an object instance in C#, JSON or XML.

Answer (score 1):

I often use the [JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to convert extensive objects to/from text for unit testing purposes:

```
var fruits = new List<string>();
fruits.Add("Apple");
fruits.Add("Banana");
fruits.Add("Blueberry");
fruits.Add("Orange");

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var text = jss.Serialize(fruits);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

The code above will produce the following output:

```
["Apple","Banana","Blueberry","Orange"]
```

Which can be converted back to an object like shown below:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var text = "[\"Apple\",\"Banana\",\"Blueberry\",\"Orange\"]";
var fruits = jss.Deserialize<List<string>>(text);
```

This workaround has saved me from a lot of boring typing ;)