# serialize object to c# object literal in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

In visual studio, is there a way to "serialize" an object to object-literal c# notation like you can serialize an object to json? I have numerous data objects that I currently get from a database that I would like to convert to literal objects to that I can include them in unit tests without relying on a database.

For example, if I have an instance of MyClass in memory, which has string properties Prop1, Prop2,... PropN, I'd like to serialize it to a string that looks like this c#:

```
var myClass1 = new MyClass(){
     Prop1 = "value 1",
     Prop2 = "value 2",
     ...
     PropN = "value n"
};
```

Comment: There is no serializer like that, you'd have to write one using reflection. But you could serialize to XML and deserialize from XML in your unit tests using the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: I don't know of any easy way. Perhaps not a duplicate, but close: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5793867

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your best option would be default XML serialization and then conversion to string.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass)); 
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\myXml.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, details); 
}
```

Then to retrieve the values:

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\myXml.xml");
object obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
MyClass XmlData = (MyClass)obj;
reader.Close();
```

Of course you can play a lot with storing serialized classes in single files etc but then it becomes a file merging/splitting issue.

Answer (score -2):

You should use:

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

(Example included)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough - I don't want json output, I want c#.

Comment: So basically you need to convert CLR object into the C# code that will construct and initialize this object with this values?

Does the properties are only string? because if there not, it would be hard